# After closing the lid Mac didn't ask for password

Tags: sleep-wake

This is super scary. Yesterday I closed my MacBook's lid in the evening. The next morning I opened the lid and my MacBook didn't ask me for my password. I was already logged in.

[image]

This seems like a bug, but how can I trust that my Mac to lock my user when I close the lid? I think I will have to logout which is annoying. Has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the 'System Preferences > Energy Saver' pane for both the 'Battery' and 'Power Adapter' tabs? It's possible one of the settings in this area is affecting the sleep habits of your Mac.

Comment: Try resetting your SMC.

Comment: @SkeletonBow it happened once. But that's the problem isn't it? security should never fail.

Comment: That's correct. Maybe you could try contacting Apple about it, though with an issue like this (which is so intermittent and seemingly unreproducible), I'm not sure it'll do a lot of good

Comment: Do you remember if the laptop had logged in instantly? Or did it have to wake up from sleep, and then log in itself? If it's the latter, then it would be more of an issue with your laptop not going to sleep on time

Comment: @SkeletonBow I think your spot on, screen was on.